# mysqli_prepare() returning NULL because it does not recognize the '?'

Tags: php, variables, mysqli, null, return

I have the following code.

`       $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'zyk', 'nuithadit6-6-6', 'phpAdv');

```
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() )
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno() );
    exit();
}

    $thisDB = mysqli_prepare($db, "CREATE DATABASE ?");
    echo mysqli_stmt_error($thisDB);;`
```

When running this code, I get the following warning:

PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpAdvanced/cap1/createDB.php on line 13.

If I change the second parameter to the mysqli_prepare function to the following:

"CREATE DATABASE myDB"

then the Warning goes away. It seems that mysqli_prepare does not like it when the query string has variables in it, and it returns NULL for $thisDB when I use it in this way. As far as I understand, this is NOT the expected behavior.

I've been reading on the manuals and forums, and still no answer yet. Does anybody knows why the mysqli_prepare is not returning the appropriate value?

The version of mysqli is 5.0.8, and my version of php is 5.3.15.

Comment: Bind variables can only apply to __data values__, not to table, column or database names

Comment: What does `echo mysqli_error($db);` print?

Comment: The `mysqli_stmt_error($thisDB);` prints the error string in case mysqli_prepare() function returned an error while executing. What kind of error? Could be an error parsing the statement fed as input argument, or any other error related to the database connection, as far as i understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepared statements do not accept placeholders for anything that is a MySQL identifier. This includes database, table and column names. You should simply concatenate a sanitised version of your table name to your statement and use `mysqli_query()`.

The reason is this: MySQL will parse a prepared statement and prepare a complete execution plan when you prepare it. This includes which tables it will use, which indexes, and how it will select from the columns. When you execute the statement it substitutes the variable data into the execution plan and creates a result.

If you try and prepare a statement including a MySQL entity like a table as an unknown, MySQl is unable to create the execution plan.

Comment: I understand now. Do you have any reference you can point me to so I can get deeper into this? If not, I suppose I will have to read the php manuals better. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: There's a good overview on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). The definitive reference for MySQL is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)